# Restricting access on parent directories but enabling read-write access for subdirectories

Tags: debian, permissions

I want to know if it's possible to recursively restrict read and write access to a folder with subfolders and files but enable it for only one subdirectory?

Example directory structure:

```
dir/
-- subdir1/
---- file1
---- file2
---- subsubdir1/
------ file1

-- subdir2/
---- file1
```

In this case there should be read and write restrictions for a specific user on everything except for `subsubdir1` and its files. Is that even possible? (I'm using Debian 11)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is!

```
cd $HOME
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
mkdir -p parent/child/subitem
chmod 100 parent
cd parent
ls
cd child
ls
```

Does that do what you want?

If you put something in parent, like:

```
touch $HOME/tmp/parent/an_item
```

You should really chmod that `an_item` directly.

You should take a look at the user, group, and everyone paradigm for permission controls if you don't know it. You can just change the ownership (`chown`) of the one folder. If you have an account and someone else has an account, you can own some of the folders, and have the other account own the subfolder, or vice versa. Or, you can create a group for users, and have that group associated with the special folder. Add the other account to said group, and it gets access to the folder; assuming you set up the permissions on the folder/file correctly. [More details on permissions](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/) and [more details on groups](https://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/).